# Bootloader issue with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server

Tags: server

After doing a fresh installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server system is not booting directly but when I go to bios and Exit it then it's booting up. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have seen dust making my GPU undetectable, try cleaning up the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

run `sudo apt update`to update APT package manager.

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

open **boot-repair** and go to the **Advance options**
select **main Option** and select the **grub reinstall** option 
**apply**

try this it may be helpful

thank you